# How to get the counts display only once for each same character?

Tags: java

I have this code which is working fine but the thing is that the result is showing as below.

```
public static int[] countlist (char[] list){

    int [] counts = new int[list.length];

    for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {

         for (int m = 0; m < list.length; m++) {
            if (list[m] == list[k]){
                counts[m]++;
            }
        }



        System.out.println( "Letter " + list[k] + " = " + counts[k]);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Letter T = 1
Letter T = 2
Letter N = 1
Letter T = 3
Letter Z = 1
Letter N = 2
Letter H = 1
Letter H = 2
```

How do I have to do to get the output for each letter once?
Thanks alot 
For example, I want output to be like below

```
Letter T = 3
Letter N = 2
Letter Z = 1
Letter H = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a HashMap to hold the counts/frequency of individual characters.

Traverse through your list and for each element do:

- if the element is not present in the HashMap, insert it with the frequency 1
- if the element is present in the HashMap, increase the frequency by 1.

At the end, printing the key/value pairs of the HashMap will give you the desired output.

Comment: Exactly what I was attempting to say, but your answer is more clear, nice!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with java yet that I can type the code quickly now but basically you can create an array and have the keys be the letters and the values the values of the letters

in PHP this would work something alike:

```
$array = array();

$array['T'] = 1;
$array['T'] = 2;
$array['T'] = 3;
$array['N'] = 2;
$array['Z'] = 1;
$array['H'] = 2;

echo print_r($array); //Resulting in T=>3, N=>2, Z=>1, H=>2
```

If you don't want the first value of (for example) T to be overwritten all you have to do is implement an IF statement checking if $array['T'] already exists.

EDIT:
in your provided code you would have to implement it where I've marked it:

```
public static int[] countlist (char[] list){

    int [] counts = new int[list.length];

    for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {

         for (int m = 0; m < list.length; m++) {
            if (list[m] == list[k]){
                counts[m]++;
            }
        }

        //====Insert the code here====

        System.out.println( "Letter " + list[k] + " = " + counts[k]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitive arrays to store the result is mandatory? You could use a Hashmap and define the letter as the key and the counter as the value.

```
Map<Character, Integer> charactersOccurrences = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++) {
    if (charactersOccurrences.containsKey(list[k])) {
        charactersOccurrences.put(list[k], charactersOccurrences.get(k) + 1);
    } else {
        charactersOccurrences.put(list[k], 1);
    }
}
```

Then to print:

```
for(char aLetter : charactersOccurrences.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("Letter " + aLetter + " = " + charactersOccurrences.get(aLetter));
}
```

Comment: Yes it is mandatory. Is there any other way to do without using Hashmap?

Comment: The problem I see is that you want to associate each character to a integer, which are different types, so we couldn't use a two dimensional array. I would say to create a object with a char and int attributes, then an array of it, and do something similar to Hashmap. Are you allowed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void countlist (char[] list)
{
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (int k = 0; k < list.length; k++)
    {
        if (map.containsKey(list[k]))
        {
            map.put(list[k], map.get(list[k]) + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            map.put(list[k], 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) 
    {
        System.out.println( "letter = " + entry.getKey() + ", count = " + entry.getValue() );
    }
}
```